# Determine the values of $r$ where $f´(0)$ exist.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

### If $r>0$ is rational, let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$, whit $f(x)=x^r\cdot\sin(1/x)$ for all $x \neq 0$ and $f(0):=0$, determine the values of $r$ where $f´(0)$ exist.

I dont know hoy can I determine the values of r.

Comment: Just write down the definition of $f'(0)$, remembering that $f(0)=0$.  Use that $\sin$ is bounded.

Comment: You may as well compute $|f'(0)|$

Answer (score 1):

Hint :

$f'(0)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(h)}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{h^r\sin(\frac{1}{h})}{h}=????$

Comment: You plugged in the wrong thing; you replaced $r$ with $h$

Comment: @Nameless : Thank you :)